# iphone cache misses

Tags: iphone, caching, profiling

is there a way to profile cache misses in an iphone application?

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/SharkUserGuide/GettingStartedwithShark/GettingStartedwithShark.html

tells that there is a 'Hardware Measurements' Profiling mode in Shark which enables L2 cache miss profiling - however, i don't get this mode displayed in shark (i'm using the latest iPhone SDK)

any hints on that?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Shark has an option to record L2 Cache misses but I have never seen this work. Personally I think this is something that is used by Apple internally and not exposed to us third-party developers. File a bug, maybe they will change their mind. Or fix it if it is supposed to work.